# in xampp localhost not working , local network ip works for an project

Tags: php, cakephp, localhost

I am working on project with Cake PHP, I configured in local with XAMPP, When I tried to access with `localhost/projectName` it is not loading, But loading by targeting with local IP address like `192.168.1.234/projectName`. I have included the images.

[image: LocalHost]

[image: LocalIp]

Comment: xampp wok i that way.  I would you suggest to use Vagrant and run this setup . https://github.com/salines/vagrant-cakephp

Comment: this has nothing with using vagrant or not.

Comment: `localhost` is 127.0.0.1. Is the Apache configuration set to listen on that address?